Window.open() forgets previous window name after reload/postback
I have a workflow that at the end of postback has to open a popup window. Now most browsers block popups not originating from a user event, so we did the following:

Upon the user click open the popup to avoid blockage, it opens up with a plain loading screen. We named the window "X"
The background page posts back
At the returned response, it finalizes the request parameters and makes a hidden form to be submitted, with window target as "X".

This has been working fine for us, until recently where a specific user is getting a problem. The JavaScript at the time of response does not find any existing "X" window and thus, opens a new one. So we end up with two popups, one being the actual workflow and other the placeholder loading screen.
I have tried to identify any chrome setting but I could not find any.
P.s. same computer works fine with edge.
Any ideas?
Simplified Code of what we are doing;
<script>
    form1 = document.getElementById("form1");
    form2 = document.getElementById("form2");
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if(canProceed) { //will be false when the page first opened, set from sever side
            window.open('', "X", "top=0,left=0,status=1,toolbar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1");       //second window.open() call
            form2.setAttribute("target", "X");
            form2.submit();
        }
    });

    function beginSequence() // called upon a user click
    {
        window.open('localhost/placeholderloadingscreen', "X", "top=0,left=0,status=1,toolbar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1");         //first window.open() call
        form1.submit(); //causes the page to postback so I cant capture the variable from previous line
    }

</script>


window.open(url,'X') followed by <form target="X"> followed by window.open(url,'X') ? If the form target changes the URL, then the name will be gone for security reasons. Doubly so if the url changes origins. Only way you can do this is to have the content of the window in an iFrame. If all the pages are same origin, then use a modal dialog and AJAX  instead

I will try this... But the window name persists for everyone. It does not work in chrome for just a single user. Any chrome setting that affects this behaviour?

Post simplified code of what you're doing. It may sound obvious to you because to you it may appear to be only one way to implement this but actually there are several very different ways to do what you describe so I'm not sure which of the 3 different ways in my mind right now you are having problems with.

For example, 2 of the 3 ways I'm thinking about involves saving the return value of window.open() to a variable. And later when I have the final URL I will be doing something like variable.location = newUrl. So I have no idea how you lose a variable you created because you must have it in the closure or if not using a closure you must have saved it in some object right? Unless it's a React thing then yes, useState can be tricky.

Added the simplified code in the question. No React just plain javascript/jquery.
